# Email validation client side

Tags: javascript, client-side, email-validation

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="book-list">
 <div class="form-group">
   <label for="email">Email</label>
   <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control">
 </div>
 <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
</form>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function isEmail(email){
    return /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z](2,4))$/.test(email);
    }   
 const form = document.querySelector('#book-list').addEventListener('submit',(e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const inputEmail = document.querySelector('#email').value;
    if(isEmail(inputEmail) === false ){
      console.log('you lost');
      document.querySelector('#email').focus();
      return false;
    }else{
      console.log('you win');
      return true
    }

});
</script>
```

> Playing around with this email validation, is there anything wrong
>   with the code? even I filled the field with the proper email address like **myname@gmail.com** it kept
>   printing **you lost** result instead of printing the **you win**, is it because the form submit?

Comment: You could use [`<input type="email" />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email) instead.

Comment: For using Regex Quantifier should be in `[A-Za-z]{2,4}`. And Not `[A-Za-z](2,4)`. Try this modified regex : `^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$`

Comment: I got fixed it, I didn't pay attention to the bracket, Thank you everyone!

Comment: @DaviddeLavign - The Regex pattern you have used for validation of email is wrong in this part - `[A-Za-z](2,4)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use input `type='email'` if you want to allow html5 to do the validation for you, the submit wont fire if the field is not valid.

Otherwise you can change your regexp a bit to the below one

```
([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your regular expression is the syntax for 2 to 4 characters.

Instead of `(2,4)` it should be `{2,4}`

```
function isEmail(email){
    return /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/.test(email);
}

isEmail('email@example.com')
// true
```

---

However, you may want to just use HTML's built in `email` type for your input. This will probably be more reliable than any regular expression you could could craft.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression in the function isEmail is not correct. Change it to this

```
function isEmail(email){
 return /^([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$/.test(email);
 }
```

Then you will get the right response when you submit with a valid email.